# How do I monetize a Discord community server?

Tags: finance

So 6 months ago I created a Discord community server for a speedrunning community for a game I moderate on speedrun.com. While it hasn't been doing that well, I am trying to plan ahead and am trying to find ways to monetize my community when it does start to see some growth.

I have not been able to find a whole lot of specifics on the monetization of Discord servers.

I am aware of Discord monetization for servers, which have the requirements of having 2FA enabled, no policy violations, and the server not primarily being 18+, in turn giving the ability to earn income by selling digital goods/experiences, being able to reward and create a home for super supporters, and 90% revenue share.

As far as I'm aware, monetization rewards might be only for the server owner, but I don't really know the specifics aside from that, as that's the only info Discord gives about server monetization.

I am aware of incorporating ads (I don't know how), but this sounds like something that would be really hard to implement.

However, my question is, are there any other ways to monetize a Discord community server that I am not aware of?

Comment: This question is missing a key detail: To what end are you trying to monetize the community? To fund community initiatives, to pay for professional services, to make the labor sustainable, and - no judgment - if it's personal profit, it's personal profit. But the end goal informs the means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would focus more on gaining members and then being able to retain those members, monetizing wont do you much good if you don't have an active community that's willing to support you or showing interest in your idea. Once you have a good solid plan and foundation for your members and being able to hold members and keep them active by holding events, giveaways, etc. then you can start worry about how to monetize and start being able to fund yourself with it. Once you get a good amount of activity, ask your community, interact with them, make polls and see what kind of content they would want to see or what kind of events they would like to do, data will be most valuable for you to then plan your long term goals